# is the set of matrices with 2's on the diagonal open or closed?

Tags: general-topology, matrices

I want to find and prove that the set of matrices with 2's along the diagonal is open or closed.

Let the set of matrices with 2's along the diagonal be $M_2 \subseteq\Re^{n\times n}$. Now there are several definitions of open and closed sets so I am not sure which one to use to prove this. I saw somewhere that a set is closed if it contains all of its boundary points. I am thinking I could prove this by contradiction and show that the boundary point cant be contained in $R\backslash M_2$? even then the definition of a boundary is tough to understand.

Comment: Here's a hint: Fix a real number $r$ and a coordinate position $(i,j)$ where $i,j\leq n$. Consider the set $S(r;i,j)$ consisting of all matrices such that the $(i,j)$ coordinate is $r$. Is $S(r;i,j)$ open, closed? Once you know this you'll know the answer for $M_2$ since $M_2$ is the intersection of $S(2;i,i)$ for all $i\leq n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the convergent sequence characterization of closed. So let $(A_n) \subset M_2$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathfrak{R}^{nxn}$. Well, since it is in $M_2$, we have that all its diagonal elements are 2. But then its limit $A$'s diagonal elements are also 2, so $A \in M_2$, and we get that $M_2$ is closed.

Since $\mathfrak{R}^{nxn}$ is connected and $M_2 \ne \mathfrak{R}^{nxn}$, we get that $M_2$ is not open.